# Resizing browser window in flutter web, without any overflow (like normal web sites do)

Tags: flutter

I need to deploy a full dashboard app to the web, but when resizing the browser's window, various components overflow.

I am aware that SingleChildScroolView could solve this and there are also 2D scrolling after Flutter 3.13, but either approaches seem to be an hack around something that should have it's own solution / or component.

**The quick question:**

*How could we make it so, that whatever is the body of our app, it behaves like a normal webpage (scroll/overflow wise)?*

**or:**

If that is not possible and we do need to take into account what is inside the body (individually/by sections), then what is the principle and the logic ?

In my particular example, I have customScaffold that is used across the app and it's mainly compose by:

- a side menu
- a top header (with page names, buttons, row of cards, etc)
- a body, where a PageView is the parent, and content is organized inside different pages - (each page can have whatever it's needed, could be a entire dashboard, could be Rows, Columns, etc)

This is an illustrative example:
[image]

I feel like I am missing something, but would like to have a comprehensive answer that can help my case and others. Thanks.

Other questions I look into:

- [Flutter web: How to allow overflow outside browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596148/flutter-web-how-to-allow-overflow-outside-browser-window)
- [Handling overflow in Flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989012/handling-overflow-in-flutter-web)

Comment: You might want to look here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html.